# How can I get sheet range(s) from a list of individual cell row and column positions?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an appscript that updates some data in a sheet. Once data has been updated I want to protect that data so that a user can not modify it.

Currently I have a function that returns a 2D array corresponding to row and column positions of individual cells. I tried iterating through this array and applying protection on a cell by cell basis takes too long so I'm trying to create a function that would take this cell position array and return an array of ranges.

For example:

cellsToProtect=[[1,1][2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,6]]

Here there is a range starting at row 1, col 1 and ending at row 2, col 4.
There is also a single cell which is not part of a bigger range at row 5, col 6.

I'm trying to work out how to make a makeRange function that given this array would return:

[[1,1,2,4],[5,6,1,1]]

ie: 
A range starts at row 1 col 1 and extends for 2 rows and 4 cols.
Another range starts at row 5 col 6 and extends for 1 row and 1 col.

It should be easy but I'm just not able to get my head around it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to do something like this. I have to run so I wasn't able to test it for small mistakes but it should give you the general idea of what to do! Essentially, you are moving through cellsToProtect 2 elements at a time and getting a range from those 2 elements.

```
var ranges = [];
for(var i = 0; i<cellsToProtect.length; i+=2){ //Important i+=2 we want to move 2 each time.
  var startRow = parseInt(sheet.cellsToProtect[i][0])+1;
  var startCol = parseInt(sheet.cellsToProtect[i+1][0]);
  var endRow = parseInt(sheet.cellsToProtect[i][1])+1;
  var endCol = parseInt(sheet.cellsToProtect[i+1][1]);
  var numRows = endRow - startRow;
  var numCols = endCol - startCol;

  ranges.push(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols]);
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant, thanks so much that worked a charm! Minor mistakes are that startRow and endRow both need + 1 to make them into sheet indexes instead or array indexes. The for loop declaration should be i<cellsToProtect.length

Comment: I've fixed the things you mentioned.